# Python regex replace numbers < 100 with '100 BLOCK', else replace last two digits with '00 BLOCK'

Tags: regex, python-2.7, list

I am using **Python 2.7.13** to clean some data.

I have a list of numbers that if strings starting with numbers. If the starting number is less than 100, I need to replace it with `'100 BLOCK'`. If the number is greater, I need to replace the *last two digits* with `'00 BLOCK'`.

The list of text is guaranteed to start with a number 0 or greater.

Example

```
'1234 foo foo' --> '1200 BLOCK FOO FOO'
'19 bar bar' --> '100 BLOCK bar bar'
'0 baz baz' --> '100 BLOCK baz baz'
```

Currently, I run two different regex expressions in a for loop:

```
for row in listOfNumbers:
    /* Replace last two digits with '00 BLOCK' */
    firstRegex = re.sub(r'^(\d*)\d{2}\b', r'\g<1>00 BLOCK', row)

    /* Replace digits under 100 with '100 BLOCK'. This includes 0 */
    secondRegex = re.sub(r'^(\d{1,2})\b', '100 BLOCK', firstRegex)

    /* Do other stuff with results
```

Is it possible to somehow do this in one regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
strs = ['1234 foo foo', '19 bar bar', '0 baz baz']
rx = re.compile(r'^(?:(\d{1,2})|(\d+)\d{2})(?!\d)')
for s in strs:
    print(rx.sub(lambda x: '100' if x.group(1) else x.group(2)+"00", s))
```

Output:

```
1200 foo foo
100 bar bar
100 baz baz
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6MJ0hO)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(\d{1,2})|(\d+)\d{2})` - a non-capturing group matching 2 alternatives:

  - `(\d{1,2})` - Group 1: one or two digits (<100)
  - `|` - or
  - `(\d+)\d{2}` - Group 2 capturing one or more digits and then any 2 digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit to the right is allowed.

If Group 1 matched `100` is used to replace the match, else, the Group 2 contents with `00` appended to it are returned.

Comment: Stribizew thanks! I added in the 'BLOCK' and it works great. Just curious though, I am vaguely familiar with lambda functions and I'm wondering where does the value for 'x' get passed in to the lambda function?

Comment: @siushi See `lambda x: ...`